# Transforming a raster .png image to vector file

Tags: arcgis-pro, georeferencing, vectorization

[image: image is a zoomed-in screenshot of the .png raster i am trying to vectorize]I have been working with FEMA flood maps to georeferenced and then digitize the maps by hand drawing polygons of the flood zone features. I have tried some workarounds to make the digitization process more accurate and faster, for example tried raster to polyline feature in ArcGIS Pro to vectorize the .png file. My goal is to take the cells with a value of 1 and transform these into vector lines. This somewhat worked... it took about 4 hours to run and the output was a ton of small vector feature, which did not make the vector features any more accurate than if I do it by hand. I am just curious if anyone has tried something like this in the past and if they found any workarounds.

Comment: Maybe you could attach an image of what the raster looks like? How did you do the raster to line operation?

Comment: @Berend i used raster - polyline conversion tool. I didn't have an option for raster to line. I tried to use only the '1' value cells and did 'nodata' for the 0- the issue partly I think is that the background shading of some of the floodzones have values of 1 which I don't want in the final vector output

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally one would have used [ArcScan](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm) in ArcMap to aid in vectorization of  b&w rasters, such as you are showing. If you have access ArcMap, then try it. The ArcScan extension is not available in ArcGIS Pro and following this [idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcscan-and-raster-clean-up-support-in-arcgis-pro/idi-p/973908) over on the Esri forum site it does not look like it will ever be ported into the ArcGIS Pro environment.